# How to declare pointers to member functions in a class initializer and call through those pointers?

Tags: c++

I want to build a table in my class that contains pointers to member functions. The MS C++ (Visual Studio 2015) compiler complains about the initializer for the _requests table in the class, and the usage of std::bind. The compiler's error messages aren't very helpful:

> 1>d:\temp\win32project1\win32project1\source1.cpp(59): error C3867:
>   'tlv::parse_read': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to
>   member
>
> 1>d:\temp\win32project1\win32project1\source1.cpp(62): error C3867:
>   'tlv::parse_write': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer
>   to member
>
> 1>d:\temp\win32project1\win32project1\source1.cpp(40): error C2440:
>   'initializing': cannot convert from 'std::_Binder &>' to
>   'std::function'
>
> 1>  d:\temp\win32project1\win32project1\source1.cpp(40): note: No
>   constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload
>   resolution was ambiguous

Placing an ampersand in front of the routine names in the table just changes the error to an illegal operation on a bound member function

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

enum TLV_TYPE : uint32_t
    {
    tlv_type_read,
    tlv_type_write
    };

typedef struct
    {
    TLV_TYPE    type;
    uint32_t     length;
    } TLV_RECORD, *pTLV_RECORD;

typedef function <uint32_t (const TLV_RECORD& Record)> pTLV_PARSER;

typedef struct
    {
    TLV_TYPE            type;
    pTLV_PARSER         parse_routine;
    } TABLE, *pTABLE;

class tlv
    {
    public:
        tlv ()
            {
            };
        ~tlv ()
            {
            };

        uint32_t start_parse (const TLV_RECORD& Record)
            {
            pTLV_PARSER parser = std::bind (_requests [0].parse_routine, this, placeholders::_1);
            parser (Record);
            return 0;
            };

    protected:

        uint32_t parse_read (const TLV_RECORD& Record)
            {
            cout << "parse read: type " << Record.type << endl;
            return 0;
            }

        uint32_t parse_write (const TLV_RECORD& Record)
            {
            cout << "parse write: type " << Record.type << endl;
            return 0;
            }

        const TABLE _requests [2] =
            {
                {tlv_type_read, parse_read},
                {tlv_type_write, parse_write},
            };

    };  // End of class tlv

int main ()
    {
    tlv         foo;
    TLV_RECORD  rec = {tlv_type_read, 4};

    foo.start_parse (rec);
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: `{tlv_type_read, parse_read}` should be `{tlv_type_read, &parse_read}` and ditto for the following line, to shut up the first two compiler warnings.

Comment: *"The compiler's error messages aren't very helpful:"* - Visual Studio 2015? ... Compared with the kind of error messages produced by C++ compilers decade(s) ago, this is a really helpful error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to initialize _requests in the constructor initializer list of tlv so that there will be a `this` pointer that you can bind. I also recommend using a lambda function instead of std::bind because they are typically faster.

```
tlv () :
    _requests{
        {tlv_type_read,  [this](const TLV_RECORD& Record){ return parse_read(Record); }},
        {tlv_type_write, [this](const TLV_RECORD& Record){ return parse_write(Record); }}
    }
{
}

uint32_t start_parse (const TLV_RECORD& Record)
{
    pTLV_PARSER parser = _requests[0].parse_routine;
    parser (Record);
    return 0;
};

const TABLE _requests [2];
```

Answer (score 2):

What you're effectively trying to do in your `tlv::_requests` initializer is convert a pointer-to-member to an `std::function` but there is no implicit conversion.

It looks like the correct solution would be to change your `TABLE.parse_routine` member to be a pointer-to-member-function instead of an `std::function` (you don't need `std::function` for what you are doing):

```
uint32_t (tlv::*parse_routine)(const TLV_RECORD &);
```

(For the compiler to accept this, you need to forward declare the `tlv` class by adding `class tlv;` prior to the definition of the `TABLE` struct.)

You also need to adjust your syntax for taking the member pointers:

```
            {tlv_type_read, parse_read},
            {tlv_type_write, parse_write},
```

Should be:

```
            {tlv_type_read, &tlv::parse_read},
            {tlv_type_write, &tlv::parse_write},
```

Then, when invoking this function, you don't need to use `std::bind` at all, just do:

```
(this->*(_requests[0].parse_routine))(Record);
```

Comment: thank you for your help. The compiler is confused by the definition of the parse_routine pointer; it doesn't compile because it doesn't like the class tag, it claims it is a function returning function, and that 'uint32' is a missing return type. I added a declaration of class tlv; just before the definition of the struct.

Comment: My bad, since you declare that struct before the class, you need to add a forward declaration of the class (`class tlv;`) prior to the definition of the `TABLE` struct so the compiler knows that `tlv` exists. And `uint32` should be `uint32_t`, just a typo on my part.  I will add this info to my answer.

Comment: I get the following error on the line declaring parse_routine:
1>d:\temp\win32project1\win32project1\source1.cpp(28): warning C4121: '<unnamed-tag>': alignment of a member was sensitive to packing

Then, on the lines declaring the table initializers, I get:
1>d:\temp\win32project1\win32project1\source1.cpp(80): error C2276: '&': illegal operation on bound member function expression

And finally, on the line invoking the parse_routine, I get:
1>d:\temp\win32project1\win32project1\source1.cpp(62): error C2296: '.*': illegal, left operand has type 'tlv *const '

Comment: In order, my comments on the errors: (1) are you using `#pragma pack`? (2) Try instead using `&tlv::parse_read` and `&tlv::parse_write`. (3) Did you change `tlv::start_parse` to be a `const` method? If so the the code in your question is out of date. This can be fixed by changing `TABLE.parse_routine` to `uint32_t (tlv::*parse_routine)(const TLV_RECORD &) const;` Note that `tlv::parse_read` and `tlv::parse_write` will have to be made `const` as well.

Comment: 1. Nope, no #pragma pack. Looking at the MS compiler help: "The compiler added padding to align a structure member on the packing boundary but the packing value is less than the member's size". I suspect that I don't need to be too concerned about this
2. Adding the class type fixed that problem (although I don't understand why, because the initialization is within the class definition)
3. No, I didn't make any of the methods const, or make any other changes that you didn't specify. I tried making them all const just to see if that would help, but it didn't

Comment: Oh jeez, I mis-parsed the type. It's because `this` is a pointer, not a reference/object. Silly me. The proper pointer-to-member invocation syntax against pointers is `->*` not `.*`. Updating answer.